# Exoplayer2 in recyclerview video pause on notifyitemchange is called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-video-player, exoplayer2.x

I have the task to make video play in `recyclerview` use exoplayer
and use this [reference](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/867) :

I am follow [tutorial](https://androidwave.com/exoplayer-in-recyclerview-in-android/) by Droid wafe :

and code works very well in my application. but. there is a slight problem. the problem is when I call the `notifyItemChange` (position) function to update an item on videoViewHolder. the video paused, but the audio still runs in the background.

I think the problem is when `notifyItemChange` is called, video view holder in re-create and make the video pause (default) but audio keep running cause not calling `setplaywhenready(false)`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.*;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.TrackGroupArray;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.*;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;
import es.hyrax.zonapets.R;
import es.hyrax.zonapets.data.network.model.post.Post;
import es.hyrax.zonapets.ui.user_private.home.dashboard_my_zona.viewholder_myzona.ViewHolderImages;
import es.hyrax.zonapets.ui.user_private.home.dashboard_my_zona.viewholder_myzona.ViewHolderMultipleImages;
import es.hyrax.zonapets.ui.user_private.home.dashboard_my_zona.viewholder_myzona.ViewHolderVideos;
import es.hyrax.zonapets.utils.listener.OnDoubleClickListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
public class ExoPlayerRecyclerViewMyZona extends RecyclerView {

    private static final String TAG = "ExoPlayerRecyclerView";
    private static final String AppName = "ZonaPets";
    /**
     * PlayerViewHolder UI component
     * Watch PlayerViewHolder class
     */
    private ImageView mediaCoverImage, volumeControl;
    private FrameLayout container_volume;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private View viewHolderParent;
    private AspectRatioFrameLayout mediaContainer;
    private PlayerView videoSurfaceView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer videoPlayer;
    /**
     * variable declaration
     */
    // Media List
    private ArrayList<Post> mediaObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    private int videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = 0;
    private int screenDefaultHeight = 0;
    private Context context;
    private int playPosition = -1;
    private boolean isVideoViewAdded;
    private RequestManager requestManager;
    // controlling volume state
    private VolumeState volumeState;
    private int targetPosition;

    private OnEventClickVideoViewHolder onEventClick;



    public ExoPlayerRecyclerViewMyZona(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ExoPlayerRecyclerViewMyZona(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        Display display = ((WindowManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
            getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))).getDefaultDisplay();
        Point point = new Point();
        display.getSize(point);

        videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = point.x;
        screenDefaultHeight = point.y;

        videoSurfaceView = new PlayerView(this.context);
        videoSurfaceView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector =
            new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        //Create the player using ExoPlayerFactory
        videoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
        // Disable Player Control
        videoSurfaceView.setUseController(false);
        // Bind the player to the containerView.
        videoSurfaceView.setPlayer(videoPlayer);
        // Turn on Volume
        setVolumeControl(VolumeState.ON);

        addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (mediaCoverImage != null) {
                        // show the old thumbnail
                        mediaCoverImage.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    }

                    // There's a special case when the end of the list has been reached.
                    // Need to handle that with this bit of logic
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                        playVideo(true);
                    } else {
                        playVideo(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });

        addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull View view) {
                if (viewHolderParent != null && viewHolderParent.equals(view)) {
                    resetVideoView();
                }
            }
        });

        videoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, @Nullable Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups,
                                        TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                switch (playbackState) {

                    case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Buffering video.");
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (volumeControl != null){
                            volumeControl.setAlpha(1f);
                        }

                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Video ended.");
                        videoPlayer.seekTo(0);
                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_IDLE:

                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_READY:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Ready to play.");
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                        }
                        if (volumeControl != null){
                            volumeControl.setAlpha(1f);
                        }
                        if (!isVideoViewAdded) {
                            addVideoView();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });
    }

    public void playVideo(boolean isEndOfList) {

        int targetPosition;

        if (!isEndOfList) {
            int startPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
                getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int endPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            // if there is more than 2 list-items on the screen, set the difference to be 1
            if (endPosition - startPosition > 1) {
                endPosition = startPosition + 1;
            }

            // something is wrong. return.
            if (startPosition < 0 || endPosition < 0) {
                return;
            }

            // if there is more than 1 list-item on the screen
            if (startPosition != endPosition) {
                int startPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(startPosition);
                int endPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(endPosition);

                targetPosition =
                    startPositionVideoHeight > endPositionVideoHeight ? startPosition : endPosition;
            } else {
                targetPosition = startPosition;
            }
        } else {
            targetPosition = mediaObjects.size() - 1;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "playVideo: target position: " + targetPosition);

        // video is already playing so return
        if (targetPosition == playPosition) {
            return;
        }

        // set the position of the list-item that is to be played
        playPosition = targetPosition;
        if (videoSurfaceView == null) {
            return;
        }

        // remove any old surface views from previously playing videos
        videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView);

        //set get target position to this target position
        this.targetPosition = targetPosition;

        int currentPosition =
            targetPosition - ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
                getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        View child = getChildAt(currentPosition);
        if (child == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (child.getTag() instanceof ViewHolderVideos) {
            ViewHolderVideos holder = (ViewHolderVideos) child.getTag();
            if (holder == null) {
                playPosition = -1;
                return;
            }
            mediaCoverImage = holder.img_post;
            progressBar = holder.progressBar;
            volumeControl = holder.volumeControl;
            viewHolderParent = holder.itemView;
            container_volume = holder.container_volume;
            requestManager = holder.requestManager;
            mediaContainer = holder.mediaContainer;

            videoSurfaceView.setPlayer(videoPlayer);

            mediaContainer.setOnClickListener(new OnDoubleClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDoubleClick(View v) {
                    onEventClick.onDoubleClickListener(targetPosition);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                    onEventClick.onSingleClickListener(targetPosition);
                }
            });

            container_volume.setOnClickListener(new OnDoubleClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDoubleClick(View v) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                    toggleVolume();
                }
            });


            DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                context, Util.getUserAgent(context, AppName));

            String mediaUrl = mediaObjects.get(targetPosition).getImagepost().get(0).getVideo();/*"https://androidwave.com/media/androidwave-video-1.mp4";*/

            if (mediaUrl != null) {
                MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl));
                videoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
                videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }
        }else {
            videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the visible region of the video surface on the screen.
     * if some is cut off, it will return less than the @videoSurfaceDefaultHeight
     */
    private int getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(int playPosition) {
        int at = playPosition - ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
            getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        Log.d(TAG, "getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight: at: " + at);

        View child = getChildAt(at);
        if (child == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int[] location = new int[2];
        child.getLocationInWindow(location);

        if (location[1] < 0) {
            return location[1] + videoSurfaceDefaultHeight;
        } else {
            return screenDefaultHeight - location[1];
        }
    }

    // Remove the old player
    private void removeVideoView(PlayerView videoView) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) videoView.getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return;
        }

        int index = parent.indexOfChild(videoView);
        if (index >= 0) {
            parent.removeViewAt(index);
            isVideoViewAdded = false;
            //viewHolderParent.setOnClickListener(null);
        }
    }

    private void addVideoView() {
        mediaContainer.addView(videoSurfaceView);
        isVideoViewAdded = true;
        videoSurfaceView.requestFocus();
        videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        videoSurfaceView.setAlpha(1);
        mediaCoverImage.setVisibility(GONE);
        volumeControl.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

    }

    private void resetVideoView() {
        if (isVideoViewAdded) {
            removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView);
            playPosition = -1;
            videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            mediaCoverImage.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            volumeControl.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    private Boolean currentPositionIsVideoType(){
        int currentPosition =
            targetPosition - ((LinearLayoutManager) Objects.requireNonNull(
                getLayoutManager())).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        View child = getChildAt(currentPosition);
        if (child == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (child.getTag() instanceof ViewHolderVideos) {
            return  true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void releasePlayer() {
        if (currentPositionIsVideoType()) {
            if (videoPlayer != null) {
                videoPlayer.release();
                videoPlayer = null;
            }

            viewHolderParent = null;
        }
    }

    public void onPausePlayer() {
        if (currentPositionIsVideoType()){
            if (videoPlayer != null) {
                //videoPlayer.stop(true);
                videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                videoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
            }
        }
    }

    public void resumePlayer() {
        if (currentPositionIsVideoType()){
            if (videoPlayer != null) {
                videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                videoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
            }
        }
    }

    private void toggleVolume() {
        if (videoPlayer != null) {
            if (volumeState == VolumeState.OFF) {
                Log.d(TAG, "togglePlaybackState: enabling volume.");
                setVolumeControl(VolumeState.ON);
            } else if (volumeState == VolumeState.ON) {
                Log.d(TAG, "togglePlaybackState: disabling volume.");
                setVolumeControl(VolumeState.OFF);
            }
        }
    }

    //public void onRestartPlayer() {
    //  if (videoPlayer != null) {
    //   playVideo(true);
    //  }
    //}

    private void setVolumeControl(VolumeState state) {
        volumeState = state;
        if (state == VolumeState.OFF) {
            videoPlayer.setVolume(0f);
            animateVolumeControl();
        } else if (state == VolumeState.ON) {
            videoPlayer.setVolume(1f);
            animateVolumeControl();
        }
    }

    private void animateVolumeControl() {
        if (volumeControl != null) {
            volumeControl.bringToFront();
            if (volumeState == VolumeState.OFF) {
                requestManager.load(R.drawable.ic_volume_off)
                    .into(volumeControl);
            } else if (volumeState == VolumeState.ON) {
                requestManager.load(R.drawable.ic_volume_on)
                    .into(volumeControl);
            }
            //volumeControl.animate().cancel();

            volumeControl.setAlpha(1f);

            volumeControl.animate()
                .alpha(1f)
                .setDuration(600).setStartDelay(1000);
        }
    }

    public void setMediaObjects(ArrayList<Post> mediaObjects) {
        this.mediaObjects = mediaObjects;
    }

    public void setVideoViewHolderClickListener(OnEventClickVideoViewHolder onEventClick){
            this.onEventClick = onEventClick;
    }


    /**
     * Volume ENUM
     */
    private enum VolumeState {
        ON, OFF
    }

    public interface OnEventClickVideoViewHolder {
        void onSingleClickListener(int position);
        void onDoubleClickListener(int position);

    }

}
```

and log cat not show any error!!

please take a look my comment in [issue report](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/867#issuecomment-534382701) for help understand

Comment: any solution to this? having similar issue here